# C++ Boost ASIO socket errors

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost, cmake

I just installed CLion today on my new Linux environment and I decided to try to make a simple socket server. I eventually want to create a socket server in C++ (because I already made tons in C#, Java, Python, PHP, Node.js...).

I got the following code:

```
//
// Created by josh on 10-10-16.
//

#ifndef RANDOMPROGRAM_TEST_H
#define RANDOMPROGRAM_TEST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;

class test {

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    tcp::socket socket;

    test() {
        this->acceptor = tcp::acceptor(this->io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 30000));

        this->socket = tcp::socket(io_service);

        acceptor.async_accept(this->socket, boost::bind(&this->handle_accept, this, this->socket, NULL));
    }

    void handle_accept(tcp::socket* client, const boost::system::error_code& error) {

    }
};
#endif //RANDOMPROGRAM_TEST_H
```

In my main .cpp file (which gets called when the program is executed):

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    test t();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Randomshitprogram)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(Boost 1.62.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

if(Boost_FOUND)

    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp test.h)
add_executable(Randomshitprogram ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Now, when I try to execute the program, it gives the following error, together with possibly a ton of errors:

```
No matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_socket_acceptor()’
```

The log:

http://pastebin.com/a09FvuTk

Answer (score 4):

> when I try to execute

you mean compile, right? That's a compile error, not a runtime one.

> `No matching function for call to 'boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_socket_acceptor()'`

The constructor for [boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor.html) is documented here. There is no default constructor, which is what your compiler is telling you.

You're invoking (or trying to) the default constructor here:

```
test() /* here */ {
    this->acceptor = tcp::acceptor(this->io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 30000));

    this->socket = tcp::socket(io_service);

    acceptor.async_accept(this->socket, boost::bind(&this->handle_accept, this, this->socket, NULL));
}
```

where there is no initializer list. Any data members of `test` must be constructed *before* the body of your constructor.

Your constructor *should* look something like this:

```
test()
: acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 30000))
, socket(io_service)
{
    acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&this->handle_accept, this, this->socket, NULL));
}
```

Comment: It fixes the error but still I got some more errors. One I see is: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_stream_socket(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&)’
         acceptor.async_accept(this->socket, boost::bind(&test::handle_accept, this, this->socket, boost::asio::placeholders::error));